# Wordpress new version Version 5.3.2, user login not working after upgrade

Tags: login

After upgrade to wordpress new version 5.3.2, user login from frontend is not happening. Admin login is working fine. User side, its login and redirected to profile page, but i think session value not updating. When i write a hook to execute after login of user, its execution, then again showing login option in website. I checked with ultimate member login also. Now elementor login popup form is in my website. In both case same issue happening. Please help.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: php version is 7.2